# using data from a text file

Tags: java, file-io

[This is the website](http://en.literateprograms.org/index.php?title=Special%3aDownloadCode/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm_%28Java%29&oldid=15444) of the Dijkstra's algorithm I am studying, but the data of the of the edges are created inside the program. What I want is to have the data as a text file, I have made a text file and also able to read it line by line as a String.

But I cant find out how I can use these data from the text file within the program. can anyone give me any suggestions please?

my data looks like this, is creating a graph

Starting point, End point, Cost

2 3 1

2 4 1

2 5 2

2 6 2

3 1 1

3 2 1

3 4 1

---

This is the code I have for now to read the file, i can print out all the lines or a specific line, it read the data in an arraylist. but i would like to do the line split (String[] fields = line.split(" ");) is so i can print out one number in the data. But is not allowing me to do so when i put it in the code, can anyone add it for me please.

File file = new File("data1.txt");

```
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(scanner.nextLine());

        }
        scanner.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");  
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i <lines.size(); i++){

        String getlines = lines.get(i);

    }

        System.out.print(lines.get(0)+"\n");

}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file using the following code:

```
    File file = new File("YOUR_FILE_PATH"); 
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file); 

        scanner.nextLine(); // to ignore the first line which has the header

        ArrayList<GraphNode> graphList = new ArrayList<GraphNode>();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] fields = line.split(" ");

            // Do something with these values
            graphList.add(new GraphNode(Integer.parseInt(fields[0]),
                                        Integer.parseInt(fields[1]),
                                        Integer.parseInt(fields[2]));

        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You should be consistent when you create your file either to make the separator `,` or `space` because in your example you have the header separated by `,`, while the data are separated by `space`

You can have a simple class to hold your data, e.g.:

```
class GraphNode {
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int cost;

    public GraphNode(int start, int end, int cost) {                
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.cost = cost;
    }

    public int getStart() {
            return start;
    }

    public void setStart(int start) {
            this.start = start;
    }

    public int getEnd() {
            return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(int end) {
            this.end = end;
    }

    public int getCost() {
            return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for everyone's reply, didnt expect to have comments so quickly, really helpful for someone like me whos new to java. 
Anyway, I understand how i can print each fields now. But if inside the program i only want to access line number 5, how can i do that?

Comment: I have taken out the heading now as the user will not need to know these information. What im really stuck on now is to get the code into some kind of a GUI that the user can interact with. But before doing that I will have to connect the number of the graph into the algorithm, can you give me some help or directions how i can do that? thanks

Comment: You can read all your data in an `ArrayList` of some structure e.g. `Graph Node`. Then you will have the control which value to retrieve and what to display.

Comment: i have written some code, can you take a look for me pls.thanks

Comment: See my updated answer, it shows you how you can read the file into some simple data structure

Comment: I see so now i can use these getstart methods in my program, now i will try to connect the numbers into the algorithm. thank you so much!

Comment: hi there is me again, im trying to put all the data into the program, to make a graph, well thats what my teacher said....but what i dont get is how do i know if it is in a map, he told me not to make the GUI yet be4 all the classes are done....just wonder if u can help me out on this...

Comment: well i think my main question is how can i use the data like i have now but doing the same function as the follows...
 
 Vertex A = new Vertex("1"); 
 A.route = new Edge[]{ 
 new Edge(B, 2),
   new Edge(C, 1),
 new Edge(F, 3),
 new Edge(G, 3)
 };

Answer (score 0):

You put the data from the text file into (in your case) a sort of string array/list/whatever suits your purpose using a loop. You can then grab them by their index fx. to do math with them.

If you want to convert them from string type to number types afterwards, you use the parseInteger method (fx and if your only dealing with integers) to convert them into the correct datatype. Obviously there's a parseFloat method aswell for the float class and so on and so forth.

After you have read the file and inserted the data into a string array of some kind. I suggest you place them in a new array of an appropriate datatype using a loop and using the parse methods to convert them.

After that you can get the values from the new array and do math with them if that's what you need.